# C# Variable value based on OS

Tags: c#, operating-system

I would like to ask if there is any possibility to declare variable based on OS.

For example I would like to change a variable dllName if I use mac to  joinery_solver_pinvoke.dylib and if windows to .dll.

```
  internal class Unsafe
  {
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Basic Method and Examples for PInvoke
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //private const string dllName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? "joinery_solver_pinvoke.dll" : "joinery_solver_pinvoke.dylib";
            private const string dllName = "joinery_solver_pinvoke.dll";
    
    }
```

Comment: You’ve commented out your use of IsOSPlatform? That will work, but the value can’t then be `const`

Comment: Define an abstract class, and platform specific sub-classes. With `[SupportedOSPlatform]` attributes to ensure that you've put the appropriate platform checks in the right places. Otherwise you could use `#if` tests, but then you'd need to build separate assemblies.